Is it possible to use the same IPv4 on multiple servers running apps on different ports?
My setup;

5+ dedicated servers connected through a switch
/20 public IPv4 subnet on the switch
Bridge network setup so any dedicated can use any IP from the /20 for any app

I want to be able to run different services running on different ports and different dedicated servers but same IPv4.
For example;

App1 running on port 1111 on Server1 on IP 1.2.3.4
App2 running on port 2222 on Server2 on IP 1.2.3.4
App3 running on port 3333 on Server3 on IP 1.2.3.4

Is this possible? If it matters, these "apps" will be docker containers running certain apps actually.

Yes, but practically only through assigning that IP address to one device that would DNAT the packets to one or another server's internal address. Basically the same way one uses "port forwarding" at home.
This is already something Docker does by default when it's told to expose a port – each container has its own address, but Docker automatically sets up DNAT on the host OS (which acts as a gateway/router) to share the host's IP address between multiple servers running in containers.
To share a single address between several physical hosts, however, DNAT will need to be set up on the gateway that's common for all those hosts. If you have no control over the gateway that's currently used, then one of the hosts will need to become the new gateway for the other hosts that need to "share" its address (the rest remaining the same – the gateway host owns the address and DNATs connections port-by-port to the other servers).
It might be possible to achieve this without NAT, using iptables marks and policy routing, but I feel it would create more new problems than it would solve – and it is still unavoidable that the configuration would have to be done on a gateway.
If they're all HTTP-based webapps, it might be easier to set up a reverse proxy.
